# selecting specific element within one parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is my HTML form structure:

EDIT: Each section is generated by PHP script, and the section id will change depending on user input. I am not able to use the whole selector because of this

```
<section id="JaneDoe">
<div class="gcolumn1">Jane Doe</div>
<div class="gcolumn2">Color:
    <input type="radio" name="chk_clr[]" id="chk_clr[]" value="Y">Yellow
    <input type="radio" name="chk_clr[]" id="chk_clr[]" value="R">Rose
    <br>Food:
    <input type="radio" name="JaneDoe-chk_food[]" id="chk_food[]" value="Y">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="JaneDoe-chk_food[]" id="chk_food[]" value="N">No</div>
<div class="gcolumn3">
    <select id="Meal[]" disabled>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
        <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style="clear: both; height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

```
<section id="JohnSmith">
    <div class="gcolumn1">JohnSmith</div>
    <div class="gcolumn2">Color:
        <input type="radio" name="chk_clr[]" id="chk_clr[]" value="Y">Yellow
        <input type="radio" name="chk_clr[]" id="chk_clr[]" value="R">Rose
        <br>Food:
        <input type="radio" name="JohnSmith-chk_food[]" id="chk_food[]" value="Y">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="JohnSmith-chk_food[]" id="chk_food[]" value="N">No</div>
    <div class="gcolumn3">
        <select id="Meal[]" disabled>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
            <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
</section>
```

I'd like for the dropdown `Meal[]` to be enabled only after the `chk_food[]` is selected as yes. However, I am having some trouble figuring out how to tell jQuery to enable only the dropdown box within the same section.
I currently have this as the jQuery: (I added the alert boxes to see which part of the code is not working)

```
var update_meal = function () {
      alert ("Hi");
      var sec_id = $(this).closest("section").attr("id");
      alert (text(sec_id));
      if ($(sec_id + "> #chk_food[]").is(":checked")) {
          $(sec_id + "> #Meal[]").prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
          $(sec_id + "> #Meal[]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      }

  };
  $(update_meal);
  $("#chk_food[]").change(update_meal);
```

When I tried to run this on JSFiddle, no bugs show up, but the coding doesn't work at all. 
I see the alert box popping up with "Hi" as soon as the document loads

Thank you for your help

Comment: Quote **whole** selector. Don't use the same id on a page.

Comment: Each section is generated by PHP script, and the section id will change depending on user input. I am not able to use the whole selector because of this

Comment: The last part of your code has no sense. E.g. it should be `sec_id + " > #chk_food[]"` instead of `sec_id > "#chk_food[]"`.

Comment: `sec_id > "#chk_food[]"` – you are making a _comparison_ using the “greater than” operator here … which of course is _not_ what you want.

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested, still no luck. I added more information about what I tried in the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements on the same page with the same ID. It is invalid HTML and it will confuse your code terribly. To get this to work, you first need to use classes to find things:

```html
<section>
   <div class="gcolumn1">JohnSmith</div>
   <div class="gcolumn2">Color:
      <input type="radio" name="chk_clr[]" value="Y">Yellow
      <input type="radio" name="chk_clr[]" value="R">Rose
      <br>Food:
      <input type="radio" name="JohnSmith-chk_food[]" class="chk_food yes" value="Y">Yes
      <input type="radio" name="JohnSmith-chk_food[]" class="chk_food no" value="N">No
   </div>
   <div class="gcolumn3">
      <select name="Meal[]" class="meal" disabled>
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
         <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
         <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both; height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
</section>
```

Then you can start to target things correctly. Something like this:

```js
$(".chk_food").on("change", function() {
   $(this)
      .closest("SECTION")
      .find("SELECT.meal")
      .prop("disabled", $(this).is(".no"));
});
```

In this case, we bind the change handler on both the Yes and No food radios. The handler will be called for the one the user clicks on, so they are inherently turning that one "on". So we find the parent section, and then the `meal` select within it, and set its disabled property to `true` if this is the `.yes` radio and `false` if this is the `.no` radio.

I think that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for sorting out my huge mess of code, and offering an elegant solution.